# Is there a way to obtain all sales and expenses data using the Quickbooks Online API?

Tags: python, api, quickbooks

I'm attempting to work with sales and expense data from a Quickbooks account (in python), in order to build a dashboard for presenting this data that can be updated in real time. I haven't come across a way to obtain this data in one API call while reading the documentation, but am wondering if I overlooked something. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's *lots* of different kinds of expense and sales data, so you're probably not going to find *one* API endpoint that gives you *all* of the data you need. Hard to tell though, since your question is incredibly vague in terms of describing what you actually need.

I would probably look at the reports endpoints, and see if there is a report (or multiple) that give you want you want:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/report-entities/accountlistdetail